# File System replace multiple strings at once?

Tags: node.js, filesystems, discord.js

I am trying to replace a few things here in discord.js using File System, however, whenever I run the command it still doesn't replace the wanted strings.

**Definitions:**

**args** is Argument/User input, **user** is @User which returns as @userID>, **inv** is File location and **cdir** is Directory location

So lets say I run the command, with the file name **TEST**, and the user **@Kart**, with the input as **Potato**. I want the bot to return the message as only **> Potato**, however its giving me **> @Kart TEST Potato**

```
  fs.writeFile(`./char_inv/${cdir}/${args[1]}inv.txt`, inv + `\r\n` + `> ${args.join(" ").replace(/args[1]/g, "").replace(/user/g, "")}`, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out

```
  var repl = args.join(" ")

  repl = repl.replace(args[0], "")
  repl = repl.replace(args[1], "")
  repl = repl.replace(args[2], "")




  fs.writeFile(`./char_inv/${cdir}/${args[1]}inv.txt`, inv + `\r\n` + `> ${repl}`, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    })
```